# Endless Recyclerview переходит в начало

Tags: android, recyclerview

1) При загрузке новых данных через rest api навигация сразу перемещается в начало. Т.е. данные новые загрузились, но сразу в начало идет.

```
mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycleralda);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

 mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                visibleItemCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (loading) {
                    if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                        loading = false;
                        previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    }
                }
                if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                        <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    currentPage++;
                    populateData();
                    // End has been reached

                    Log.i("...", "end called");

                    // Do something

                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });

    public void init() {
        mRecyclerviewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(lNews,getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerviewAdapter);
        mRecyclerviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: если вы после загрузки новых данных вызываете метод `init()`, то список и будет перемещаться в начало потому, что вы создаете новый адаптер. В каждом вопросе должна быть только одна проблема, для дубликатов в `ArrayList` создавайте новый вопрос

Comment: ну а как сделать чтобы он не переходил в начало?)

Comment: @Radzhab типичный ответ в русскоязычном сообществе.

Такая же проблема )